# Possible to make WebBrowser control share cookies with HttpWebRequest?

Tags: .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

is there a way to make the WebBrowser control in C#.NET and requests made by HttpWebRequest share cookies?

E.g. if a request is made programmatically with HttpWebRequest and then the HttpWebResponse sets a cookie, is there a way to make sure this is also set in the WebBrowser control?

and likewise, if the user navigates with the WebBrowser control and a cookie is set, is there a way to ensure the CookieContainer for the HttpWebRequest is also updated?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to synchronize the cookies manually using the `InternetSetCookieEx / InternetGetCookieEx` APIs, and this would require that you know all of the URLs of all of the subdownloads used by the page in question.

You also need to pass the `INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` flag to ensure that `HTTPONLY` cookies are seen by your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(myUri, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
```

([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c8107e4d-fe8f-4be9-81a4-0575eb72248f))

And vice versa (I'm not sure):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
//request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.GetResponse();
webBrowser1.Document.Cookie = request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(myUri);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. so you think it is not possible to do both ways?  what about if I used an alternative to the WebBrowser control? are there any alternatives which would allow me to do this?

Comment: @Jimmy: I updated my answer. Let's try. Please give know about your results.