# Using 2 WebBrowser controls and dealing with HTTPONLY cookies in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

In my application i have to login using `WebBrowser` Control and then access site using `HttpWebRequest`, to achieve this i have to transfer cookies from  `WebBrowser` Control to the `CookieContainer` of `HttpWebRequest`. I am using following code to achieve this.

```
this._cookieContainer.SetCookies(uri,GetGlobalCookies(uri));
```

here

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);
const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

public static string GetGlobalCookies(string uri)
{
    uint datasize = 1024;
    StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)datasize);
    if (InternetGetCookieEx(uri, null, cookieData, ref datasize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero)
        && cookieData.Length > 0)
    {
        return cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ',');
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Till now this code is working perfectly but i am trying to use 2 `WebBrowser` Controls to login into the same site but different accounts and as the method `GetGlobalCookies(string uri)` is static how can it treat 2 `WebBrowser` Controls differently is my question?

Actually here i am able to login into 1 account using 1 `WebBrowser` control but after that if i try to login into another account using another `WebBrowser` control its automatically redirecting to 1st account. How to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Here actual problem is using 2 WebBrowser Controls. So in order to solve this i have to synchronize cookies using InternetSetCookieEx / InternetGetCookieEx APIs as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723636/possible-to-make-webbrowser-control-share-cookies-with-httpwebrequest?rq=1)